# Can't post to PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

This question might have been asked a few times, but I couldn't find any solutions to my problem.
So I created a list consisting of names of sweets (here Marshmallow, Milk Chocolate), I want to pass this as a string to a php file using POST. Here is my current code:

```
<script>
  function passJSON(){

    var endValues = $("#sweets").val().toString();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "temporaryEchos.php",
    data: { sweetsAJAX : endValues },
    success: function(){
      var endValues = $("#sweets").val().toString();
      alert(endValues);
    }
  });
}
</script>
<button onclick="passJSON()">Click me to get data!</button>
```

$("#sweets").val() returns Marshmallow, Milk Chocolate, but I found I had to convert it to string for it to properly work.

Here's my temporaryEchos.php

```
<?php


    $sweets = $_POST["sweetsAJAX”];

echo $sweets;

foreach ($sweets as $value){
  echo "Value: $value <br>";
}
echo "sweets set successfully!";
?>
```

after clicking submit the $.ajax success function returns Marshmallow, Milk Chocolate, but the PHP only echos "sweets set successfully!". How could I go around this?

Comment: Could the problem be the mismatch between the names `sweetsAJAX` and `sweetsArray`?

Comment: Fixed but still doesn’t send!

Comment: You assume that `$sweets = $_POST["sweetsAJAX”];` will contain an array, whereas it will contain a string. You used `.toString()`.

Comment: Also `"sweetsAJAX”` has two different types of quotes.

Comment: _"after clicking submit the $.ajax success function returns Marshmallow, Milk Chocolate"_ yes, because you are setting those values directly, not retrieving them from your PHP API. Use `success: function(endValues)` to see what is being returned.

Comment: Further, you should check the documentation, `$_POST` expects an associative array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

Change sweetsArray to sweetsAJAX

```
<?php
$sweets = $_POST["sweetsAJAX"];

echo $sweets;
?>
```